# Stopping SASS Watch from a script

Tags: php, shell, command-line, sass

I'm running SASS from a script, but I'd like it to stop it after it generates the compiled CSS file rather than it continuing to "watch" the folder. Here's what I have inside:

```
exec("sass --watch --compass public/scss:public/css --style compressed --scss");
```

Normally when you run this from the terminal, you'd press "Ctrl+c" to stop SASS, but my question essentially is: how do you do that from a script (that's written in PHP)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `sass --update` instead of `sass --watch`

Try this:

```
exec("sass --update --compass public/scss:public/css --style compressed --scss");
```

Next time, you should check the documentation for the version of SASS that you have installed:

```
sass --help
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I did do "sass --help"...but I guess I just didn't see --update or think it would do what I needed.